# Ripple Transaction from one local wallet to exchange wallet(example : crex24) gives error code tecDST_TAG_NEEDED using java

Tags: java, ripple, rippled

i installed ripple wallet on my local server. i created one wallet and activate it with 20 XRP.

Now when i send coin from my active account to account(of crex24.com) then it gives tecDST_TAG_NEEDED error code

Ripple : http://127.0.0.1:5005

Code (using submit method):

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
Map<String,Object> mainMap = new HashMap<>();
mainMap.put("secret", "sxxxxxxxxxxx");
mainMap.put("Fee", "1000"); // in drops

Map<String,String> subMap = new HashMap<>();
subMap.put("Account", "raxxxxxxxxx"); // amount will be deducted from this account
subMap.put("Amount", "1000000"); // in drops
subMap.put("Destination", "rdxxxxxxxxx"); // receiver address
subMap.put("TransactionType", "Payment"); // since we are making a  payment request

mainMap.put("tx_json", subMap);

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("method", "submit");
json.put("params", new JSONArray(mainMap)); 
String requestData = json.toString();
System.out.println(requestData);
String response = template.postForObject("http://127.0.0.1:5005", requestData,String.class);
System.out.println(response);
```

Error

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "message": "Transaction achieved successfully.",
  "data": {
    "result": {
      "deprecated": "Signing support in the 'submit' command has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the server. Please migrate to a standalone signing tool.",
      "engine_result": "tecDST_TAG_NEEDED",
      "engine_result_code": 143,
      "engine_result_message": "A destination tag is required.",
      "status": "success",
      "tx_blob": "120000228000000024000000096140000000000F424068400000000000000A7321036CB83FF75DAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "tx_json": {
        "Account": "raxxxxxxxxx",
        "Amount": "1000000",
        "Destination": "rdxxxxxxxxx",
        "Fee": "10",
        "Flags": 214482148,
        "Sequence": 9,
        "SigningPubKey": "036Cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6",
        "TransactionType": "Payment",
        "TxnSignature": "txxxxxxxxx",
        "hash": "hxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  },
  "path": "/api/ripple_wallet/makeTransaction"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your account on `crex24.com` requires a `destination tag`.
`XRPL` uses `account model` similar to `ETH`. Unlike `BTC` which uses an `UTXO model`.

The reason some exchanges require `destination tag` is that you might be sharing that address with some other person on the exchange. e.g:

- `Person1`'s deposit address is: `Addr1`
- `Person2`'s deposit address is also `Addr1`
- Somebody deposits `100XRP` to `Addr1`.

In the case above the exchange wouldn't be able to differentiate if it was `Person1`'s or `Person2`'s.
So the `XRPL` introduced `destination tag` which would look something similar to this:

- Exchange sets `tfRequireDestTag` flag of the `Addr1` to `true` using [accountSet](https://developers.ripple.com/accountset.html) transaction
- `Person1`'s deposit address is: `Addr1:1234`
- `Person2`'s deposit address is also `Addr1:1235`
- Somebody deposits `100XRP` to `Addr1`. `XRPL` refuses due to `tfRequireDestTag` being set to `true` /This is your case/
- Someone sends `50XRP` to `Addr1:1234`. `<-- this one succeeds!`

Comment: Thanks, got it and also implemented it. but i can get balance of my account using "account_info" method of ripple. "account_info" method returns total balance of whole account.   but how can i get destination tag wise balances if my account has multiple destination tags? do you have any idea

Comment: oh the balance is of the account itself. `destTag` really is just an optional data of the `tx`. You have to implement a mechanism to track each `destTag`'s balance on your end. How to track is completely up to you. The important thing to remember is that the sum of all `destTag`'s balances must equal to account's balance.